# Can a StreamBuilder be outside the build method?

Tags: flutter, stream-builder

I can't find any information on where the StreamBuilder needs to be within the code so I am asking here.

I have a screen in my flutter app that has a lot of input textfields. Each textfield has this code structure:

```
TextField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  controller: clientLNameController,
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  onChanged: (value) {
                    trxnProvider.changeclientLName(value);
                  },
                  decoration: kTextFieldDecoration.copyWith(
                      hintText: 'Client Last Name',
                      labelText: 'Client Last Name'),
                ),
```

In the initState() function I call a method that pulls data from a Firestore collection and populates the TextEditingController associated with each textfield.

```
@override
  void initState() {
    getTrxn();
  }
```

It is in this function that I try to get the data using a StreamBuilder. Here is the code.

```
getTrxn() async {
    StreamBuilder (
        stream: _db.collection('agency').doc(globals.agencyId).
        collection('trxns').doc(globals.currentTrxnId).snapshots(),
        builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot trxnSnapshot) {
          if (trxnSnapshot.hasData) {
            clientFNameController.text = trxnSnapshot.data['clientFName'] ?? "";
          }
    )
    return SizedBox.shrink();
}
```

The problem I am having is when I run the code through the debugger and try to step through the code I get to the line StreamBuilder and then I am taken out of the function. None of the code inside the StreamBuilder gets executed but there is no error either.

I am thinking that I can not use a StreamBuilder outside the "build" function.

```
@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
```

Is this correct or am I missing something else?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do it like this

```
  late final StreamSubscription myStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    myStream = _db
        .collection('agency')
        .doc(globals.agencyId)
        .snapshots()
        .listen((snapshot) => clientFNameController.text = snapshot.data()?['clientFName'] ?? "");
    super.initState();
  }
```

Make sure to dispose the stream once done

```
  @override
  void dispose() {
    myStream.cancel();
    super.dispose();
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

### Throwaway expressions

Let's suppose you have a `Printer` class, where you can display a message and do something whenever a message is displayed:

```dart
class Printer {
  final void Function(String) callback;
  
  const Printer({required this.callback});
  
  void show(String message) {
    print(message);
    callback(message);
  }
}
```

Now, let's use it:

```
void main() {
  Printer(callback: (message) {
    print("Message $message was printed.");
  });
}
```

If you run this code, nothing will happen because you didn't call the `show` method. The above is an example of what I call *throwaway expression*, because nothing happens besides Dart creating an object and clearing it from memory.

The below snippet will work:

```dart
void main() {
  Printer(callback: (message) {
    print("Message '$message' was printed.");
  }).show("Hello, world!");
}
```

This will output

```
Hello, world!
Message 'Hello, world!' was printed.
```

### The `build` method

Generally, when you start a Flutter app by creating a `MaterialApp`, Flutter looks into its `home` argument (which is a Widget) and calls its `build` method. This widget will go through all its children declared inside its `build` method and will call their `build` methods. This process repeats until there is no more children.

When a Widget's `build` method is called, some logic is executed. Therefore, if you place a Widget A outside the `build` method, A's logic will not be executed (unless you explicitely call A's `build` method, but for this you will need a `BuildContext`) and it'll be a *throwaway expression*. So you're correct when you say

> None of the code inside the StreamBuilder gets executed but there is no error either.

### The solution

1. Put your `StreamBuilder` inside your `build` method.
2. [Use a `StreamSubscription`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68564679/9997212).

Comment: Thanks for both answers. I was able to get it working.